# What's the simplest way to amend a commit in order to revert the modifications made to a single file?

Tags: git, git-revert

Currently, when I have to do it, here are the steps that I follow:

- Revert the commit (without creating a new commit, of course)
- Reset all the modification introduced by the “revert,” except the one of the file that I wand to revert
- Stage the reversal of the file which I want to revert and amend the last commit

Is there a more straightforward way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo last Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-last-git-commit)

Comment: @BrianRoach this is not the same! I don't want to revert my commit. I want to amend it to reset a single file and i'm looking for a more straightforward way to do it than what i'm doing today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the previous state of the file and amend the commit.

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- file.txt
git commit --amend
```

If you don't need to amend the commit log message the last command can be

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

which doesn't even open your editor to edit the commit log, it just amends it.

Comment: Tx, but my question is on the "Alter the file to represent the state you want to be" part. I'm looking for a more straightforward way to do it that what I'm doing today (which is explained in the question)

Comment: Didn't know about the possibility to checkout a single file, thanks.